# Vulkan fragment shader input differs from vertex shader output

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan, I have written a simple program to draw lines with a fixed color, with simple vertex and fragment shaders. But the color inputs to the fragment shader are different than what is set in the vertex shader. I checked with RenderDoc, and the colors passed to the vertex shader are correct (1,1,1,1) for both vertices of a line and also checked its output; it's also the same. But in the fragment shader, the colors I am getting are (1,1,0,1). I don't understand why this is happening. Irrespective of what colors the vertex shader emits, the input in the fragment shader is always yellow.

Vertex shader:

```c
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 texcoord;
out vec4 io_color;
out vec2 io_uv;
out vec4 io_position2;
    
layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform UniformBlock_uTransform
{
    mat4 uTransform;
};
    
layout(std140, binding = 1) uniform UniformBlock_uTransform2
{
    mat4 uTransform2;
};

void main ()
{
    io_uv        = texcoord;
    io_color     = vec4(1,1,1,1); //Just to debug  it
    
    gl_Position = uTransform * position;
    
    io_position2 = uTransform2 * position;
}
```

Fragement shader:

```c
in vec4 io_color;
    
layout(location = 0) out vec4 result;
    
void main ()
{
    result = io_color;
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Added the shader code

Comment: I think the interfaces must match **completely**. Try also adding the `io_uv` and `io_position2` as an `in` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding output and input layout qualifiers to the values you pass from one shader to the other to ensure that they actually point to the same location:

VS:

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 io_color;
```

FS:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec4 io_color;
```

I recommend always using that syntax to connect shader out- and inputs.

Comment: Interface name matching is a valid thing in GLSL though. But I suppose `glslangValidator` has no way to know how to match the interface, if the shaders are compiled separately.

Answer (score 1):

Check if color write mask is not disabled for blue channel.